# ada renaming an array

Tags: arrays, ada

I am trying to use the same array for different actions instead of using 3 different arrays to save space. for example, in a certain part of my program spaces 1..5 aren't being used and another part spaces 3..8 aren't in use.

would the keyword **renames** do the trick? something like this?

```
type SharedArray is array (integer range 1..10) of integer;
array1: SharedArray;
array2: SharedArray renames array1(1..5);
```

If I'm right then array2 isn't a whole new array it just refers to array1 whenever it's values are changed?

Comment: Yes, either this or something like it should work. Like @Marc, I expected a `Constraint_Error`, and I'd suggest using an unconstrained type (he posted his answer as I was typing mine). But consider carefully whether saving a few bytes of space is worth it. You could very easily end up generating more code, costing more that the data space you save by reusing the same array. Are you on an extremely memory-constrained system? Can you just declare `array1` and `array2` in non-overlapping scopes, and let the compiler take care of memory reuse?

Comment: The challenge is to save space by using 1 array instead of 3. I could just use the subscripts of 1 array but redefining the name just makes it easier to read.

Comment: Why is this the challenge? In your sample code, the amount of space you save is trivial, and not worth the time you'll spend writing the extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same memory with a different identifier, you could use an access type.  This doesn't do anything for the subscript mapping, though.

```
procedure Array_Alias is
   type Shared_Array_Type is array (1 .. 10) of Integer;
   Array_1 : aliased Shared_Array_Type := (others => 0);
   Array_2 : access Shared_Array_Type := Array_1'Access;
begin

   Array_1(1 .. 3) := (1, 2, 3);
   Array_2(5 .. 8) := (others => -1);
   for Index in 1 .. 10 loop
      Text_IO.Put(Array_1(Index)'Img & " ");
   end loop;
   Text_IO.New_Line;

end Array_Alias;
```

Produces:

```
 1  2  3  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0
```

EDIT: Anonymous access types were added in Ada2005. For Ada95, an access type to the array type would need to be declared:

```
type Access_Shared_Array_Type is access all Shared_Array_Type;
Array_2 : Access_Shared_Array_Type := Array_1'Access;
```

Comment: i tried using the code above in the Ada95 compiler but it didn't work i had to change it up and here is what i got `type      MyArrayType is array (integer range <>) of  integer;
type myaccess is access all  myarraytype;

arr1: aliased myarraytype:=(1..10 => 0);
arr2:  myaccess := arr1'access;`

Comment: This works with Ada2005, which allows anonymous accessors. Sorry for not clarifying. For 95 you would need to define a type.

Comment: While this is technically correct, and well answers the question that was asked, it is IMHO quite evil. That isn't your fault, as the OQ is asking how to do something very squirelly. Still, I just can't bring myself to hit that uparrow...

Answer (score 2):

The first thought in my mind here was "No, this isn't going to work." But then I wrote this with GNAT GPL 2012:

```
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;

procedure Ren_Test is

   type Shared_Array is array (Integer range 1 .. 10) of Integer;

   Array1 : Shared_Array := (others => 42);
   Array2 : Shared_Array renames Array1(1..5);

begin
   Put_Line("Array1 range: " & Integer'Image(Array1'First) & " .." 
          & Integer'Image(Array1'Last));
   Put_Line("Array2 range: " & Integer'Image(Array2'First) & " .." 
          & Integer'Image(Array2'Last));
   New_Line;
   Put_Line("Dump Array1");
   for I in Array1'Range loop
      Put(Integer'Image(Array1(I)));
      if I /= Array1'Last then
         Put(",");
      end if;
   end loop;
   New_Line(2);


   Put_Line("Dump and modify renaming Array2");
   for I in Array2'Range loop
      Put(Integer'Image(Array2(I)));
      if I /= Array2'Last then
         Put(",");
      end if;
      Array1(I) := Array1(I) + 17;
   end loop;
   New_Line(2);

   Put_Line("Redump Array1");
   for I in Array1'Range loop
      Put(Integer'Image(Array1(I)));
      if I /= Array1'Last then
         Put(",");
      end if;
   end loop;
   New_Line;
end Ren_Test;
```

Running it gets me:

```
[35] Marc say: ./ren_test
Array1 range:  1 .. 10
Array2 range:  1 .. 5

Dump Array1
 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42

Dump and modify renaming Array2
 42, 42, 42, 42, 42

Redump Array1
 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42
```

I will say that I am NOT comfortable with this, primarily because I would've expected a Constraint_Error coming out of slicing a constrained array down to less than it's declared size. So I don't *know* that this is legal code, I do know that GNAT GPL 2012 compiles and runs it without a problem.

I'm much more comfortable when Shared_Array is an unconstrained array:

```
   type Shared_Array is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;

   Array1 : Shared_Array (1..10) := (others => 42);
   Array2 : Shared_Array renames Array1(1..5);
```

The latter I would expect to conform to the standard. The first, constrained form...IMHO, iffy. (But I'll leave it to the language lawyers to verify this.)

Comment: I tried going out of array2's range and then it gives a constraint error, So as long as you stay within the range it seems like it works fine.

Comment: @sergio: It's entirely possible that your code *should* raise an exception, and that GNAT has a bug that prevents it from generating proper code to do so. If I take your original code and add a procedure that takes a parameter of type `SharedArray`, passing `Array2` to that procedure does cause a `Constraint_Error`. The code Marc suggested, defining `Shared_Array` as an *unconstrained* array type, should work, and it's clearer.

Comment: I sent this over to AdaCore for them to take a look at. There's no guarantee they'll respond to a question from an unsupported user, but I do hear back from them more often than not.  If I get a response, I'll pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking explicitly for is aliasing. Aliasing of variables tends to confuse us poor humans, and can lead to some very subtle, hard-to find bugs. It makes your code bug prone and stressful to deal with. In short, aliasing is evil.

**It is also, in this case, entirely unnesscary**, thanks to the magic of a well-designed language. All you have to do is split the code that deals with the buffer differently into different routines, and as far as those routines will know, they are dealing with arrays that are only as large as was passed to them. For example, I wrote this short little bit of code:

```
with Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Ada_Slice is

   type Integer_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
   Integer_Buffer : Integer_Array (1..10) := (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

   procedure Magnify (Buffer : in out Integer_Array) is
   begin
      for I in Buffer'Range loop
         Buffer(I) := Buffer(I) * 10;
      end loop;
   end Magnify;

   procedure Swap (Front : in out Integer_Array;
                   Back : in out Integer_Array) is
      Scratch : Integer;
   begin
      for I in Front'Range loop
         Scratch := Front(I);
         Front(I) := Back(Back'First + (I - Front'First));
         Back(Back'First + (I - Front'First)) := Scratch;
      end loop;
   end Swap;

begin

   Magnify(Integer_Buffer(6..10));
   Swap (Integer_Buffer(1..2), Integer_Buffer(9..10));

   for I in Integer_Buffer'range loop
      Ada.Text_Io.Put (Integer'Image(Integer_Buffer(I)) & ",");
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_Io.New_Line;

end Ada_Slice;
```

When run, the output is of course:

> 90, 100, 3, 4, 5, 60, 70, 80, 1, 2,

(fixing the trailing comma is left as an exercise to the reader)